# Removing last random string from arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist, line

I'm making a program that displays random lines from a file but I'm a bit new to arraylists. I want to remove the most previous random line from the arraylist after it's displayed but not from the file. This is because I don't want it to be repeated. Here's my code:

```
try {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomInt = random.nextInt(50);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line.contains("!")) {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        while (line != null) {
            lines.add(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
            Random r = new Random();
            String rdmln = lines.get(r.nextInt(lines.size()));
            line1.setText("Line" + rdmln);
```

I want to be able to remove 'rdmln' from the arraylist after it has been displayed so that it won't be displayed again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do any of the approaches work for you? If so, you should mark one as accepted

Answer (score 3):

Check the [`remove(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) function. In your case:

```
//your code
String rdmln = lines.remove(r.nextInt(lines.size()));
//the rest of your code
```

`remove` will take it from the list and return it to you for use.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `remove()` method, which returns and removes the first instance of the object you specify:

```
lines.remove(rdmln);
```

If you would like some information from Javadocs, [here's the link.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

Removing random element from the list is inefficient. If you want to fetch M random elements from list of N elements, your approach will take `O(N * M)` steps.

Instead I suggest to read the whole file and then shuffle your list of string using `Collections.shuffle` (which will take `O(N)`) and then just display first M elements. This will be `O(N + M)`, which equals `O(N)`, as M <= N.