# Remove arraylist string stopping random function

Tags: java, random, arraylist, line

Thanks to the stackoverflow community, my [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768175/removing-last-random-string-from-arraylist) was fixed. However, I now have a new problem. I have some code that reads a random line from a file, displays it and now removes the random line from an arraylist so that it won't be displayed again. But now, the lines being shown aren't random. I have a file with 40 lines in it and now it's only showing the last 20 lines, in order. Here's the updated code:

```
try {
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomInt = random.nextInt(50);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line.contains("!")) {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        while (line != null) {
            lines.add(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
            Random r = new Random();
            String rdmln = lines.get(r.nextInt(lines.size()));
            line1.setText("Line" + rdmln);
            lines.remove(rdmln);
```

The remainder of the code repeats the process from 'lines.add(line)' to 'lines.remove(rdmln)' but instead, it displays 'rdmln2' on the label 'line2', then removes 'rdmln2' and so on. Can anyone see what might be causing this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot your code yourself by validating each line code

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomInt = random.nextInt(50);
```

Check the output of this random number, also I didn't see even you are using it anywhere in your shown code

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line.contains("!")) {
```

The above code will look for `!` at very first line of your text file, if not found, then it won't add to your list. So, make sure your first line must contains `!`.

```
  List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
  while (line != null) {
        lines.add(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
        Random r = new Random();
        String rdmln = lines.get(r.nextInt(lines.size()));
```

You have declared List with `0` size and started adding element to your list till end of the file. If you noticed then, you have created new `Random` class instance inside your while loop where you are passing your list size, which was initially `0` but after adding first elements became `1`. So technically, It will return `1` and likewise after each iteration random value range will increase and so the return value.

This means, you need to review below line, which you wrote inside your loop

```
         Random r = new Random();
        String rdmln = lines.get(r.nextInt(lines.size()));
```

Since, you are looking for random line. Then, there should be counter inside your loop to get your random line from file, which I didn't see in your code.